# 4 quadrants - trigonometry functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Given that

$y= \frac{\cos x}{\sin( x )-2} $

Find the values of $x$ between $0$ and $2\pi$ for which y has a stationary value .

First , I differentiate it -

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2 \sin(x) -1}{(\sin x-2)^2} $

Set $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 $

$\sin x = \frac{1}{2} $

$x= \frac{\pi}{6} $

However , I noticed that there are two answers . I looked at the sin graph and I can't find $x= \frac{\pi}{6} $ .

I looked it up on the internet and it tells me because $\sin x$ is positive in the first 2 quadrants .

I don't quite understand so what if it's positive , why must there be 2 values ? 
Any help to know when will there be a two value answer for sine and cosine would be appreciated . ( I'm not learning about tangent yet)

[image]

Comment: $\sin x=1/2$ for $x=\pi/6$ and $x=5\pi/6$ modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: I can't find $x=\pi/6$. Do you mean that you cannot read a plot ?

Comment: You posted the graph of $y = \cos x$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Notice that $\sin(\theta)$ is the $y$ coordinate of the point forming an angle of $\theta$ with the positive x-axis.

If you consider $\sin(\theta)$, notice that there are two points with the $y$ coordinate being $0.5$ on the circle, and only one point with the $y$ coordinate equal to $1$. Similarly for $\cos(\theta)$, there are two points with the x-coordinate equal to $0.5$ and only one point with the x-coordinate being equal to $1$.

Remember that this is where sine, cosine, tangent, and trigonometry came from, the functions that is. Trigonometry rose from triangles.